# In a large corporation withnsalespeople, every 10 salespeople report to a local manager, every 10 local managers report to a district manager...

Tags: combinatorics

> In a large corporation with n salespeople, every 10 salespeople report to a local
>   manager, every 10 local managers report to a district manager, and so forth
>   until finally 10 vice-presidents report to the firm’s president. If the firm has n
>   salespeople, where n is a power of 10, find and solve recurrence relations for
>
> a) The number of different managerial levels in the firm
>
> b) The number of managers (up through president) in the firm

I don't know how to come up with the divide-and-conquer recurrence relations. This is what I have so far for part a:

If you let $a_n$ = the # of managerial levels for n salesperson, we have the cases

$a_{10}=1$

$a_{100}=2$

$a_{1000}=3$

I notice that log(10) = 1, log(100) = 2, log(1000) = 3, and so on, but don't know how to continue.

Comment: Use geometric sum and solve for k(numbr of levels)

Answer (score 2):

This ia a partial answer. You could represent the recurrence relations in the following way:

a) Let $a_k$ be the number of managerial levels when there are $n = 10^k$ sales people. Then the recurrence relation would be

$a_k = 1 + a_{k-1}$

with $a_0 = 0$.

The solution would be $a_k = k$.

b) Let $a_k$ be the number of managers when there are $n = 10^k$ sales people. Then the recurrence relation would be

$a_k = 10^{k-1} + a_{k-1}$

with $a_0 = 0$.

The solution would be $a_k = \sum_{i=1}^k 10^{i-1} = \frac{(1-10^k)}{(1-10)}$.

Comment: I got this question from an exercise in the divide-and-conquer section of my textbook. So is it possible for the recurrence relation to include someting like $a_{\frac{n}2}$?

Comment: Well, you could change a) to $a_n = 1 + a_{\frac{n}{10}}$ and b) to $a_n = \frac{n}{10} + a_{\frac{n}{10}}$, in both cases with $a_1 = 0$. Is that what you had in mind?